# jQuery selectmenu version 1.10 not triggering change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I've added the jQuery version of 1.10 to my project and the selectmenu widget and I cannot get the change event to fire.

The selectmenu was working fine before i upgraded to the 1.10.

What do I need to do to get this working?

```
var getProjectInfo=function(){

}

--I've tried this way

   var sel = helper.selectMaker.makeSelect(data);
       sel.change = getProjectInfo;
       $('#projsPH').appendChild(data);
       $(sel).selectmenu();


--And this way

**This way throws an error of selectmenu widget does not have a method change.

   var sel = helper.selectMaker.makeSelect(data);
       $('#projsPH').appendChild(data);
       $(sel).selectmenu('change', getProjectInfo);
```

------------Update
I've got it to work like

```
$(sel).selectmenu({change:getProjectInfo});
```

But the selection will not collapse

Got the styles from Google

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.css?r=2776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using very outdated files. And I guess you are talking about jQuery UI 1.10.

Try the older but updated version: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/
Not sure of this version will work without problems with UI 1.10, not tested yet

Or, better, use the official but yet unreleased version: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu

Comment: I did download the new version of the selectmenu yesterday along with the jQuery 1.10, and the new .css files for the slectmenu. It is working now. Now that I see your name I download you're version of the selectmenu. Good work!

Comment: Would you mind marking this answer as correct? Still need more reputation points...

Comment: @fnagel +1 After upgrading a site to jquery 2.0.3 and jQuery UI 1.10.3, I also upgraded to your latest version of jquery.ui.selectmenu at https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/zipball/selectmenu and it is working fine for me. Thanks for the good work! :-)